# Closed Question Despite 8 Upvotes and Detailed Attempts – Seeking Clarification

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

I joined Math Stack Exchange about 15-17 days ago, so I might not know all the rules for asking questions. One of my early questions got closed, but it had 8 upvotes, and I mentioned what I tried. I’m confused about why it was closed.

Here is the link of the question

[Integration of $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \log(1-\cos x) \,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4858415/1285841)

I know it might not be right to ask two questions at once Stil The question is short, so I’m asking it here.

The question is can I post about recommendations for books on real analysis, number theory, Galois theory, etc.? And can someone recommend challenging questions related to number theory, Galois theory(examples) specific topics?

This is the only things I didn’t get; otherwise, my experience on the site has been wonderful

Comment: Posts asking for textbook recommendations have been posted before, so I'd suggest searching for those earlier questions rather than duplicating them. Same might be true for requests for challenging questions, so again I'd say, search before asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The very first comment asked "What exactly is your question?". It got 9 upvotes - that's a lot. And as I glance over it now, it's still not clear what you're asking.

And now with this question here, you've mixed together two issues.

So .... this isn't a site where we just kinda throw around math stuff. The organization is

- ask a question,
- make it clear so that others don't waste their time having to figure out what the deal is,
- if people are confused, and tell you so, edit your question to clear up the confusion,
- one question per post, please,
- and have fun. Welcome to Math.se!